# Is it possible to open .dmp Files in VSCode.dev

Tags: visual-studio-code, dump

If I open my .dmp File locally, it opens with VS2013 and shows everything correctly. When I now try to open the .dmp File in https://vscode.dev/ it tells me that it can't open binary and basically gives me the same as when I would open the .dmp with Notepad++.

Is there a way to use VSCode.dev to open and read .dmp Files easily?